# Heterogeneous containers in C++

Tags: c++, stl, containers, heterogeneous

I saw this nice graphic which classifies which STL container would suit based on different requirements of data such as:

-- Fixed Size Vs Variable size

-- Data of same tyme Vs different type

-- Sorted Vs unsorted data

-- Sequential Vs random access

http://plasmahh.projectiwear.org/cce_clean.svg

I notice in that image, that C++ STL there is no container which is

1. Variable Size
2. Heterogenous (data of different types).

Doesn't C++ have something for this?

PS - There can be many permutations made out the different properties of the containers and many others too might not be provided in STL.

Comment: From the image I could make out that many containers like `vector`, `queue`, `stack` etc. are shown as **variable size** based on their colors. Not sure though.

Comment: you can use a vector of pointer to abstract base class, even if other solutions are probably better

Comment: This graphic isn't about the STL, it is about the C++11 standard library.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well generally C++ Containers are designed to hold objects of a single type using templates. If you want different types that are all derived from one type you can store a container of pointers (I guess you could also have a container of void* to anything...) e.g. std::vector<MyBaseType*>.

If you want completely unrelated types, you can store objects that can safely reference those other types, such as boost::any.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html

Some examples off the boost site:

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using boost::any_cast;
typedef std::list<boost::any> many;

void append_int(many & values, int value)
{
    boost::any to_append = value;
    values.push_back(to_append);
}

void append_string(many & values, const std::string & value)
{
    values.push_back(value);
}

bool is_int(const boost::any & operand)
{
    return operand.type() == typeid(int);
}
bool is_char_ptr(const boost::any & operand)
{
    try
    {
        any_cast<const char *>(operand);
        return true;
    }
    catch(const boost::bad_any_cast &)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

boost::variant is similar, but you specify all the allowed types, rather than allowing any type in your container.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html

```
std::vector< boost::variant<unsigned, std::string> > vec;
vec.push_back( 44);
vec.push_back( "str" );
vec.push_back( SomthingElse(55, 65) ); //not allowed
```

Answer (score 10):

The basic principle in the standard library is that "containers" are homogeneous; the C++ standard doesn't consider things like `std::pair` or `std::tuple` to be containers.  (I'd consider the graph misleading, since it does consider them as containers.)  If you need a heterogeneous container, you'd have to use a container of `boost::variant`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 6):

A library which is not yet accepted into Boost. But which was proposed for inclusion is targeted toward this :

http://rawgit.com/joaquintides/poly_collection/website/doc/html/index.html

It provides a nice class named any_collection which allows one to have an heterogeneous container via boost::type_erasure::any :
http://rawgit.com/joaquintides/poly_collection/website/doc/html/poly_collection/tutorial.html#poly_collection.tutorial.basics.boost_any_collection

Otherwise in C++17 there are simple way to implement this :
https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/a-true-heterogeneous-container-in-c/

Quoting the example of the aforementioned article :

```
namespace andyg{
struct heterogeneous_container{
private:
    template<class T>
    static std::unordered_map<const heterogeneous_container*, std::vector<T>> items;
public:
    template <class T>
    void push_back(const T& _t)
    {
        items<T>[this].push_back(_t);
    }
};

// storage for our static members
template<class T>
std::unordered_map<const heterogeneous_container*, std::vector<T>> heterogeneous_container::items;
} // andyg namespace
```

Then usable easily :

```
andyg::heterogeneous_container c;
c.push_back(1);
c.push_back(2.f);
c.push_back('c');
struct LocalStruct{};
c.push_back(LocalStruct{});
```

The author states it's a toy implementation, but I think this is a really clever way to implement it, and has a simplicity advantage over poly_collection or a vector of variants.

Comment: `poly_collection` [has been accepted](https://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2017/05/0505.php) to boost 10 days after you wrote this comment.

Comment: I don't understand, can't the static variable only have a template paremeter incerted once, or does it have multiple template instantiations? Can someone point me to somewhere I could understand this sort of thing better?

Answer (score 4):

`std::pair` and `std::tuple` are hardly C++ containers.... so no, there is no heterogeneous containers in the STL, because it's not necessary to have them built-in.

There are several approaches to create such containers. The approaches I would recommend are:

- using polymorphism
- using a variant type

---

For Polymorphism, you can check [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) library.

```
boost::ptr_vector<Base> vec;
vec.push_back(new Derived);
vec.push_back(new Derived2);
```

It mimicks the STL containers, but provides functionalities geared toward polymorphism:

- Access elements as `Base&`
- Automatic memory handling
- Specific copy behavior (using `new_clone` methods)
- Syntactic sugar: given `boost::ptr_vector<Base>::iterator it;`, `*it` is a `Base&`

---

If your types are unrelated, the other possibility is to use [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html). Basically, a variant is similar to:

```
enum { Type1, Type2, ... } _type;
union {
  SomeType1 _1;
  SomeType2 _2;
  ...
} _u;
```

Of course, since it's boost, it provides specific guarantees to make sure that you can only access the member of the union that is currently active and lifts the restriction on classes with constructors / destructors not being usable in traditional unions.

It also provides facilities, like the `static_visitor`, which is the equivalent of a switch on the type, and will make the compilation error out if one of the possible states is not visited.

Answer (score 2):

The fixed size heterogenous containers (like `std::tuple` require the types to be known at compile time. If you want to make a variable sized heterogeneous container, just make a `std::vector<std::tuple<T1,T2,...,TN>>`.

If you want a heterogeneous container where the types is not known at compile time (whether that would be variable or fixed sized) you'll have to store pointers (or smart pointers) to a base type known at compile time, or alternatively consider something like a container of `boost::any`. The STL doesn't directly provide such a container in either fixed or variable sized with heterogeneous elements determined at run time.

Comment: A `std::tuple` and `std::pair` is a heterogeneous container as much as any given UDT. For instance `struct foo { int i; float f; std::string s; };`, a heterogeneous container.

Comment: +1, the STL is all about composition. There's no need to have all possible combinations pre-defined.

Comment: @dalle: Not really, you can [iterate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316573/c0x-iterating-through-a-tuple-with-a-function) through the members of a tuple.

Comment: I'm not sure how these are comments on my answer. I didn't say the std doesn't have heterogeneous containers, I just said it doesn't have containers which have an unknown type at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

If the element you store would be a [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html) then you can indirectly store heterogeneous data.

Answer (score 1):

I would point you to this library. It is implemented to be true heterogeneous container
https://github.com/hosseinmoein/DataFrame
It does not use polymorphism and consequently store pointers. It uses continuous memory storage, just like a std::vector.

You can write code like this

```
typedef StdDataFrame<unsigned long> MyDataFrame;

MyDataFrame                df;
std::vector<int>           intvec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<double>        dblvec = { 1.2345, 2.2345, 3.2345, 4.2345, 5.2345 };
std::vector<double>        dblvec2 = { 0.998, 0.3456, 0.056, 0.15678, 0.00345,
                                       0.923, 0.06743, 0.1 };
std::vector<std::string>   strvec = { "Insight", "John Dow", "Alakazam",
                                      "Persian Prince", "Bugs Bunny" };
std::vector<unsigned long> ulgvec = { 1UL, 2UL, 3UL, 4UL, 5UL, 8UL, 7UL, 6UL }
std::vector<unsigned long> xulgvec = ulgvec;

// This is only one way of loading data into a DataFrame instance. There are
// many different ways of doing it. Please see the documentation,
// or dataframe_tester.cc
int rc = df.load_data(std::move(ulgvec),  // Index column
                      std::make_pair("int_col", intvec),
                      std::make_pair("dbl_col", dblvec),
                      std::make_pair("dbl_col_2", dblvec2),
                      std::make_pair("str_col", strvec),
                      std::make_pair("ul_col", xulgvec));
```

Comment: You should generally avoid posting link-only answers. Consider adding some snippets of code along with explanations. If you wish to just share the link, it should be added as a comment on the original question instead of as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Noted all the answers mentioning about boost::variant.

But from **C++17** the standard itself provides `std::variant`. It is a type-safe union.

```
    //A vector holds multiple types as declared in std::variant.
    std::vector<std::variant<int, double, std::string>> multiTypeVector;

    //Add eleemnts.
    multiTypeVector.push_back(8);
    multiTypeVector.push_back(8.0);
    multiTypeVector.push_back("test");
    multiTypeVector.push_back("test more");

    //Testing :: print elements.
    for (auto element : multiTypeVector)
        std::visit([](auto arg) {std::cout << arg << std::endl; }, element);
```