# Nested data structure with Linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have studied many example related to linked list example but they just explain in simple way using only one structure type. So i need to dig more to clear my doubts:

```
    struct movies_t {
    int number;
    string title;
    int year;
    movies_t *next; 
    }
```

- Does all of the nodes of a linked list  necessarily  should be of **movies_t** type (as its in array:array is a collection of values of similar type) ?
- If i want to add a one or several more  different new structure dynamically and those contains completely different elements except the  `int number;` which is a common element in all data structure  to sort data orderly. Is it possible ?
- If I have to implement nested  data structures(given below), would it be possible to do it with Linked list or with some tree data structure (Binary, B, B+ trees )?

  ```
  struct movies_t {
  int number;
  string title;
  int year;
  }

  struct friends_t {
  int number;
  string name;
  string email;
  movies_t favorite_movie;
  }

  struct world_t {
  int number
  string country;
  string continent;
  double population
  movies_t favorite_movie;
  friends_t friends_forever;
  }
  ```

Comment: start from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804955/heterogeneous-containers-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class rather structure for node. Do the following,

```
class parent_t{
int number;
parent_t* next;
}

class movies_t: public parent_t {
string title;
int year;
}

class friends_t : public parent_t {
string name;
string email;
movies_t favorite_movie;
}

class world_t: public parent_t {
string country;
string continent;
double population
movies_t favorite_movie;
friends_t friends_forever;
}
```

Now, you can create the linked-list of parent_t type. Then you can insert the movie_t, friends_t, world_t type objects into the linked-list.