# What is the equivalent of QVariant in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, qtcore, qvariant

I am trying to port a Qt application to C++ using STL. What is the equivalent of `QVariant` in C++? `QVariant` can store any data type - a container that holds heterogenous - different types of objects. However, I have to port this application to C++. What is the equivalent of `QVariant` in C++?

Comment: boost::variant/boost::any

Comment: @Borgleader he asked for a STL solution.

Comment: @JameyD There arent any that I know of.

Comment: look this up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804955/heterogeneous-containers-in-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the equivalent of QVariant in C++?

The equivalent in C++ is called **`QVariant`**.

Semi-joke aside, it is probably the closest to union, but QVariant is so much more than that; meta types, CoW, etc.

Actually, sharing implicitly is forbidden these days in STL, so that is another reason why you would not find anything like this off-hand.

I would suggest to make notes to yourself what functionality exactly you need from a QVariant and make a judgement call whether it is actually worth dropping QtCore.

This is just a friendly reminder from the [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qvariant.html#details):

> The QVariant class acts like a union for the most common Qt data types.
>
> Because C++ forbids unions from including types that have non-default constructors or destructors, most interesting Qt classes cannot be used in unions. Without QVariant, this would be a problem for QObject::property() and for database work, etc.

However, since C++11 types with constructors and destructors are allowed. You have another question in here to ask from yourself:

> Do I want to support everything that Qt does or am I happy to require at least C++11?

To be fair, you could also look into the following boost variants below, but then you end up using boost instead of QtCore after the porting.

This is another judgement call for yourself. They are not replacements for each other, neither technically, nor compatibility wise.

Boost in this case is a build time dependency, while QtCore is a runtime. Qt would guarantee binary (and source) compatibility during the life cycle of the same major version, while boost may not do the same for such a long period as QtCore does.

Either way, none of these options are pure `STL` solutions in the end of the day the way I think you wanted it to.

- [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/any.html)
- [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: Well, I went back and forth at the first two lines for couple times until I notice it's a joke...can I down-vote it for wasting my precious time? Joke aside, nice answer for clarifying difference between Boost and Qt variant.

Comment: @Tay2510: it is not completely joke. If one wants to reinvent QVariant in C++, one needs to write QVariant from scratch. It is telling to tell that there is no such an alternative as it satisfies the use case what it does. Therefore, if one exactly needs, one needs to use QVariant. All the rest is compromise, not the same.

Answer (score 8):

Starting in C++17, there is [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (may contain a value of any copyable type) and [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (may contain a value of any of the given types). These will be supported out of the box in GCC 7, Clang 4.0 and Visual C++ 2017.

Neither of these is entirely equivalent (for example they don't support converting the internal value), but they will allow you to do most of what `QVariant` does.