# Python List of Dictionaries to C++

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, vector, unordered-map

I have a Python list of dictionaries that I would like to translate to C++.

My list looks more or less like this:

```
myList = [{"v_A": 5, "v_B": 3}, {"v_A": 1, "v_B":2}, {"v_A":0, "v_B": 0}]
```

My code is designed such that when I look for e.g. velocities of particle 0, I do:

```
v = myList[0]["v_"+letter]
```

where `letter` would be a string, `"A"` or `"B"`, depeding on the output of a sorting function I have.   I have found this is the most convenient way to achieve my purpose in Python.

I am trying to translate my code to C++ (being a bit of a newbie) and I don't know how I could keep the "dictionary"-like features (that is, accessing values through a key that can be built concatenating strings) and the benefits the list together like in `myList`.

I read this question without much success, being unable to understand: [C++ Equivalent of Python List of Dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987631/c-equivalent-of-python-list-of-dictionaries)

After some research, I thought of a using a vector of unordered maps, but I am unsure on how to define it and work with it. I thought of:

```
vector< unordered_map <string, int >> myList;
```

However, I am getting errors all the time. Besides, I don't know how to introduce the values in the dictionaries or access the elements. Am I approaching this from a completely wrong side?

EDIT:
I found that if I define and insert the elements piece-wise, it seems to work:

```
std::vector <unordered_map <string, int> > myList;
unordered_map <string, int> tempMap;
tempMap.insert(std::make_pair("v_A", 10));
myList.push_back(tempMap);
cout << myList[0]["v_A"];
```

returns correctly `10`. Is there a way to do this more efficient/ in a simpler way?

Comment: What errors? With what code? Please provide a [mcve] to show what you have tried doing so far

Comment: Please show what you tried and what these errors are. Although it is unclear whether this is the best approach to the problem in C++, the definition you showed should work and can be used almost the same way as in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, int>> dictList; // This is a list of dicts

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> dict; // Here we create a specific dict we want to add to our list of dicts

dict["key"] = 10; // This is how you add (key, value) pair into dict in c++

dictList.push_back(dict); // This is how you add your dict to the list of dicts
```

Comment: Best to use `push_back(std::move(dict))`—or else use `dictList.emplace_back()` to create a new, empty map *in* the vector and then populate it there.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting in the list can be done much simpler.

At initialization you can do

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, int>> myList {
    {{"v_A", 5}, {"v_B", 3}},
    {{"v_A", 1}, {"v_B", 2}},
    {{"v_A", 0}, {"v_B", 0}}
};
```

and you can later increase the size of the vector with `push_back`:

```
myList.push_back({{"v_A", 0}, {"v_B", 0}});
```

or you can add to a dictionary in one of the existing elements the same way as in python:

```
myList[0]["v_C"] = 12;
```

You cannot add elements to the vector this way though. (Accessing a vector out-of-bounds causes undefined behavior.)

Elements can be read as in Python with `myList[0]["v_C"]`.

You cannot concatenate a character or C style string to a string literal directly with `+` as in `v = myList[0]["v_"+letter]` (depending on the type of `letter` it may compile but will probably not do what you expect it to do). But if you use

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
```

after the includes in your `.cpp` file, then you can write

```
v = myList[0]["v_"s+letter];
```

The `s` suffix then causes the string literal to be converted to a `std::string`, which provides a `+` operator that actually does concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on how to add the strings! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

With a `std::unordered_map` you can use `operator[]` and if the element does not exist it will get inserted into the map.

This is not true for a vector. A vector is a dynamic array and you need to explicitly add elements to it before you can acces the already added elements with `operator[]`.

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, int>> myList;
myList[0]; // Invalid since the vector currently is empty.

myList.push_back({}); // Insert a default-constructed element in the vector

myList[0]; // Refers to the first element in the vector, which is a std::unordered_map<std::string, int>

myList[0]["string"] = 1; // This will create the elements if it does not already exist at mentioned above so this works fine
```

If you know the size you want you vector to have you can use `std::vector::resize` or a call to the constructor to set the size.

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, int>> myList(10);
// Create a vector with 10 elements, so [0-9] would be in-bounds.

std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, int>> myList;
myList.resize(10); // This will do the same thing but in two steps.
```

Comment: I will keep this in mind for the future, thank you for the advice!