# C++: class atribute in local scope

Tags: c++, global-variables

To create my own queue class, I need to declare a class attribute inside a function of this class.

What I am trying to do is :

when I call the function `add`, the program creates a new attribute to the class, in private, to access after with the operator `[]`. By this I can create a queue without type restriction, using items of any class.

Is it possible?

**Edit**

This queue is just a use sample. My really question is: in python i can do this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__ (self, ...): 
        ...
        self.color = 'blue'
```

Now, color can be used in anywhere of class (remember that don't need insert type to declare a variable in python. In the exemple, color was been declared in `__init__` scope, but is a class atribute, and not a local variable).
How I can do something like this in c++?

Comment: tuple? variadic template?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear in the first place.
From what I understand,you want to create a queue,with heterogeneous elements.You can refer this answer for heterogeneous containers.

[Heterogeneous containers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804955/heterogeneous-containers-in-c)
You can also use tuple to hold heterogenous data.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're looking for is a member variable, which must be part of the class definition because C++ is not dynamically typed.  To make it only visible within the class, make it private.  You can then set its value in the constructor initializer list.

```
class Car {
public:
  Car : color("blue") { }
private:
  std::string color;
};
```