# Store objects of different types in a container

Tags: c++, qt, containers, qt5

I have two objects `QColor`, `QFont` and there's a possibility of adding more.
I want to store that objects in a container for instance `QList` but this container needs one type of data.

```
QFont font = QFontDialog::getFont(&fontDlgRet, initFont, parent);
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(initColor, parent);
```

Is there a container accepts adding different types of objects?

Comment: Might be a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804955/heterogeneous-containers-in-c

Comment: Also, IIRC they are both derived from `QObject` so you could have a `QList<Qobject*>`.

Comment: You may want a `QList<QVariant>`

Comment: I thank everyone for your response.

Comment: @NathanOliver: QColor doesn't inherit from QObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a container accepts adding different types of objects?

Yes: QVariantList, QVariantMap, QVariantHash.

You can also roll your own manually, like `std::vector<QVariant>` for instance.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html

Also, note that loosing type information like this is frowned upon and bad practice. If you have a finite set of types you can use `std::variant` instead.