# How to create a collection of heterogeneous objects

Tags: c++

I would like to create a collection of heterogeneous objects; ie. objects of different types.

This would be useful when these objects have similar functionality (including members), but don't derive from the same parent class.

A perfect example of this are random number engines: **minstd_rand**, **mt19937** and **ranlux24** are all engines. They have the same members (such as the call operator ()), but don't derive from a common "Engine" class and so are of different types.

The same is the case with random number distributions.

Had there been a common root class 'Engine', I could easily have created a vector of these objects as follows:

```
vector<Engine> engines {minstd_rand, mt19937, ranlux24};
```

Having done this, I could then invoke a function in a loop, as follows:

```
/// Generate 10 random numbers.
void gen(vector<Engine>& engines)
{
    for (auto& e : engines)
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           cout << e() << endl;
}


int main()
{
    gen(engines);       /// Invocation
}
```

However, I can't do this.

If I use a tuple to wrap each engine, each object would have a different type:

```
tuple<type1>, tuple<type2>, ....
```

Again, the types would be heterogeneous and I couldn't create a collection of them.

So the question is, is it possible to create a collection of heterogeneous objects and if so, how?

Comment: Does your engine/wrapper template even compile?

Comment: There were some problems in the original code posted. The wrapped engines would still be heterogeneous types and so couldn't be stored in a vector. I have edited the post.

Comment: If you are going to wrap them then why not wrap then in a traditional inheritance hierarchy with a common interface?

Comment: @Galik, How can this be done? The engines don't derive from a common base class. Can you post your code, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vector<function<size_t ()>>` to hold these engines.

```
using Engine = function<size_t ()>;
vector<Engine> engines = {minstd_rand{}, mt19937{}, ranlux24{}};
for (auto &e : engines) {
    cout << e() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this solution and it works correctly. Though the underlying classes minstd_rand, mt19937 and ranlux24 are different classes, as functions, they have the same type. So the solution works! However, the original query remains : [If we aren't dealing with function objects of the same type], is it possible to store heterogeneous objects in a collection?

Comment: The [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804955/heterogeneous-containers-in-c) gives some useful answers for storing heterogeneous objects in a collection. It is marked as the "correct answer".

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create your own *polymorphic* hierarchy to wrap your different separately typed pseudo random number generators in. This is made easier by the fact that the different standard generators have a common interface even though they do not derive from a common base type.

Something a bit like this:

```
// Base interface class
class prng
{
public:
    using dist_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;

    virtual ~prng() = default;

    virtual int operator()(int min, int max) = 0;

protected:
    dist_type dist;

    template<typename PRNG>
    static PRNG& eng()
    {
        thread_local static PRNG eng{std::random_device{}()};
        return eng;
    }
};

// smart pointers because polymorphism
using prng_uptr = std::unique_ptr<prng>;

// Generic class takes advantage of the different PRNG's
// similar interfaces
template<typename PRNG>
class typed_prng
: public prng
{
public:
    int operator()(int min, int max) override
        { return dist(eng<PRNG>(), dist_type::param_type(min, max)); }
};

// Some nice names
using prng_minstd_rand = typed_prng<std::minstd_rand>;
using prng_mt19937 = typed_prng<std::mt19937>;
using prng_ranlux24 = typed_prng<std::ranlux24>;

int main()
{
    // A vector of smart base pointers to typed instances
    std::vector<prng_uptr> prngs;

    // Add whatever generators you want
    prngs.push_back(std::make_unique<prng_minstd_rand>());
    prngs.push_back(std::make_unique<prng_mt19937>());
    prngs.push_back(std::make_unique<prng_ranlux24>());

    // numbers between 10 and 50    
    for(auto const& prng: prngs)
        std::cout << (*prng)(10, 50) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I have posted a reply to your post.

Answer (score -1):

[ver 1] @Galik's post effectively demonstrated the basic technique of creating a polymorphic hierarchy, which I explain below.

The post was intended as a demonstration (rather than an implementation) of the technique involved. As such, it doesn't compile:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0465c2a11d3a0558

I have corrected the underlying issues and the following version works [ver 2]:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bb0f47251e6dfed

The technique involved is important. I have voted for @Galik's post.

However, there was 1 issue with @Galik's solution: The random_device() engine was hard-coded in the base class itself. As such, it was *always* used, regardless of which engine was passed as argument in the sub-class. In fact, the engine passed as argument to the sub-class should have been used as the source of random numbers.

I have corrected this and also changed some of the names in the following version [ver 3]:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/350eadb55a4bafe7

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>               /// unique_ptr
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

/// Declarations ...
class RndBase;          /// Random number base class

/// Generic Random number sub-class
/// takes advantage of the different Engines' similar interfaces
template<typename Eng>
class RndSub;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args);


/// Implementation ...

/// Random number base class
class RndBase
{
public:
    using dist_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;

    virtual ~RndBase() = default;

    virtual int operator() (int min, int max) = 0;

protected:
    dist_type dist;

    /// factory method
    template<typename Eng>
    static Eng& eng()
    {
        static Eng eng {Eng {}};

        return eng;
    }
};   // RndBase


/// Generic Random number sub-class
/// takes advantage of the different Engines' similar interfaces
template<typename Eng>
class RndSub : public RndBase
{
public:
    /// Generate a random number.
    int operator() (int min, int max) override
    {
        return dist(eng<Eng>(), dist_type::param_type(min, max));
    }
};


int main()
{
    using Eminstd_rand = RndSub<std::minstd_rand>;
    using Emt19937 = RndSub<std::mt19937>;
    using Eranlux24 = RndSub<std::ranlux24>;

    /// smart pointers because of polymorphism
    using pRndBase = std::unique_ptr<RndBase>;

    /// A vector of smart base pointers to typed sub-classes
    std::vector<pRndBase> prndbases;

    /// Add whatever generators you want
    prndbases.push_back(make_unique<Eminstd_rand> ());
    prndbases.push_back(make_unique<Emt19937> ());
    prndbases.push_back(make_unique<Eranlux24> ());

    /// random numbers between 10 and 50
    for(auto const& prb : prndbases)
        std::cout << (*prb) (10, 50) << std::endl;
}


template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
   return std::unique_ptr<T> {new T {args...}};
}   // make_unique()
```

The explanation of the "Polymorphic Hierarchy" pattern is as follows:
1) We know all the engines have different types, though the same interface.

2) We create an abstract base class (RndBase), which includes this interface. It also defines a parameterized (static) factory method named eng() that creates an object of the parameter Eng and returns a reference to it. It is expected that an engine would be used as the parameter.

3) We create a parameterized sub-class named RndSub that derives from the base class RndBase. This class defines a call operator which returns the random number obtained by invoking the distribution.

4) Effectively, what we have done is as follows:
   a) The heterogeneous engines are abstracted by the parameterized sub-class **RndSub**. Each sub-class is different.
   b) However, they now have a single common base-class **RndBase**.
   c) Since there is only a single base class (**RndBase**), we can now create a `vector<RndBase>`, which is homogeneous. The sub-classes of **RndBase** are heterogeneous.
   d) Since the interface is common, we can use the interface defined in the base class to invoke the implementation in the sub-class. This implementation invokes the factory method **eng**() in the base class to obtain an engine, which is passed as argument to the distribution. This returns the random number.

This solution is specifically for Random numbers. I am trying to make a solution for any classes (that have a similar interface).

Comment: In my base class, the `std::random_device` that I pass to the engin's constructor is only there to provide the ***seed*** that initializes whatever random engine you use as your template parameter. Nothing more. It is typical to use `std::random_device` because it is connected to your computers non-deterministic random number supply. My example could be improved, however bypassing the seeding engine (or just a seed value) as (say) a constructor parameter.

Comment: What you are doing here is passing an unseeded, default constructed random generator as the seeding engine to your engine. I suspect that doing that will make your random generator produce exactly the same sequence of numbers each time you run the program.